# Web Design home page doesn't show pictures

Tags: php, html, web, xampp

I have created a e-commerce website using Dreamweaver. It has a header file and a footer file. The index.php page opens the header, footer and home (basic info) pages.

There are pictures in header and footer, however when the index.php is loaded the pictures of the header and footer don't load. When I click on the menu, the pictures on the header and footer appears.

I'm using xampp and localhost

Home page no picture, any other page the pictures are loaded.

Comment: You should include your project's directory structure and the code for the header and footer. Something must be wrong with the images' paths

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for your responses. It really help.
The pictures path was wrong when loading the home page. The home page is the only page opens at the root directory, so it needed different links than the others.